# How use legacy password encryption on mysql server 5.5 win10 32bit

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, windows-10, 32-bit

I want to connect MySQL 5.5 with a Visual Studio 2017 application, because it doesn't support the newer MySQL 8.0, just 5.5... It throws this inner MySQL exception:

> authentication to host 'localhost' for user riit using method  `mysql_native_password`
>   access denied for user root@localhost(using password: YES)

I gave permission to root and I think if I set the encryption to legacy password it's fixed.

```
<connectionStrings> 
  <add name="xyconnectionstring" Server=localhost;port=3306;Database=cafeteriadb;user=root;password=password;"providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient">
</connectionStrings>
```

Code:

```
public ArrayList RetreiveAllCategoriesFromDatabase() 
{ 
   ArrayList CategoriesList = new ArrayList(); 
   using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
   { 
      MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID, CategoryName, CategoryPicture FROM Categories;", connection); 
     connection.Open();
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your C# code?

Comment: 'public ArrayList RetreiveAllCategoriesFromDatabase()
        {
            ArrayList CategoriesList = new ArrayList();

            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ID, CategoryName, CategoryPicture FROM Categories;", connection);
                connection.Open();'

Comment: That's good, but edit your question and put it there so you can apply proper code formatting. Indent with four spaces for best results.

Comment: `because it doesn't support the newer MySQL 8.0, just 5.5` what doesn't support MySQL 8.0? Visual Studio? The application? Have you installed the latest version  of Connector/Net ?

Comment: win32 doesnt support mysql 8.0 yes, connector already installed